# Ubuntu Nginx Error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect, 500-error

What is causing my redirect error after I upgraded to latest Nginx on latest Ubuntu?

```
2013/06/10 19:00:01 [error] 1078#0: *5434041 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

I have Ubuntu 13.04 Nginx ISPconfig running multiple websites.

---

My nginx conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 85;
    client_max_body_size 40m;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    client_header_timeout 240;
    client_body_timeout 240;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

---

My sites available conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
```

### }

my nginx directive from ispconfig
location ~ ..*/.*.php$ {
      return 403;
    }

```
location / {
  # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
   try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
  # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
  # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/phpcgi.socket;
}

# Fighting with ImageCache? This little gem is amazing.
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
  try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you post your config.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`.